# Javascript - Obtain Sum Totals of multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been combing through examples here and I can quite get to the answer I'm looking for.  I'm just trying to wrap my brain around javascript array manipulation, so I'm not even sure if I'm close in my code or not.

I have multiple rows in a grid on my page.  Each has a reference code (udmatlref) and a value (udmatltotal).  What I would like to do is output a list of cumulative totals for each row that contains a matching reference code.

For example, I may have

```
row#1: name:"test1" value: 904 
row#2: name:"test2" value: 796.5
row#3: name:"test1" value: 85
row#4: name:"test2" value: 907
```

I would like a result that says:

```
name:"test1" value:  989
name:"test2" value:  1703.5
```

Using what I could find here at stackoverflow, I've written the following code.  This code creates an inital array of the raw values then ends up grouping the values into a new array.  So I feel like I'm close.

```js
    function refTotals(s, e) {
            var arr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < mygrid.GetVisibleRowsOnPage(); i++) {
                var udmatlref = mygrid.batchEditApi.GetCellValueByKey(mygrid.GetRowKey(i), "udMatlRef", false);  
                var udmatltotal = mygrid.batchEditApi.GetCellValueByKey(mygrid.GetRowKey(i), "MatlTotal", false);
                if (udmatlref != null) {
                    arr.push({ name: udmatlref, value: udmatltotal});
                }
             }
            var result = arr.reduce((acc, d) => {
                const found = acc.find(a => a.name === d.name);
                const value = { value: d.value };
                if (!found) {
                    acc.push({ name: d.name, data: [value] })
                }
                else {
                    found.data.push(value)
                }
                return acc;
            }, []);
            console.log(result);
        }
```

The console log output looks like this:

```js
[
  { data: [{ value: 904 }, { value: 85 }], name: 'test1' },
  { data: [{ value: 796.5 } , { value: 907 }], name: 'test2' }
]
```

Can anybody help me log:

```
"test1" - 989
"test2" - 1703.5
```

Thank you!

Comment: please add the array/object in JSON format to the question.

Comment: Like this?    {"0":{"name":"test1","data":[{"value":904},{"value":85}]},"1":{"name":"test2","data":[{"value":796.5},{"value":907}]}}

Comment: Is that the actual input structure, or is it an array?  More like `rows = [{name: "test1", value: 904}, {name: "test2", value: 796.5}, {name: "test1", value: 85}, {name: "test2", value: 907}]`?  If this guess is correct, then `rows .reduce ((a, {name, value}) => ({...a, [name]: (a[name] || 0) + value}), {})` should yield `{"test1": 989, "test2": 1703.5}`.  If not you could replace `rows.reduce(...)` with `Object.values(rows).reduce(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your current code, your `arr` variable is an array of objects, each of which has a `name` and `value`.

We can convert this into an object, where the key is the `name`, and the value is the sum of all `value`s for that `name`:

```js
const sumByName = {}

arr.forEach(({ name, value }) => {
  if (!sumByName[name]) {
    sumByName[name] = 0;
  }

  sumByName[name] += value
})
```

After running this code, `sumByName` will be an object like:

```json
{
  "test1": 989,
  "test2": 1703.5
}
```

We can then iterate over the entries of this object to log what you want to the console:

```js
Object.entries(sumByName).forEach(([name, sum]) => {
  console.log(`"${name}" - ${sum}`)
})
```

#### Putting it together

Your existing code can be adjusted so that we build up `sumByName` directly, instead of building `arr` first:

```js
function refTotals(s, e) {
  const sumByName = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < mygrid.GetVisibleRowsOnPage(); i++) {
    const name = mygrid.batchEditApi.GetCellValueByKey(mygrid.GetRowKey(i), "udMatlRef", false);  
    const value = mygrid.batchEditApi.GetCellValueByKey(mygrid.GetRowKey(i), "MatlTotal", false);
    if (name != null) {
      if (!sumByName[name]) {
        sumByName[name] = 0
      }
      sumByName[name] += value;
    }
  }
  return sumByName
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need!  Thank you for such clean code and for breaking it down to help me learn how it's done!